# Обработка параметров запроса в AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, маршрутизация

Страница имеет кнопки пагинации и поле выбора даты. В зависимости от выбранных страницы и даты url содержит параметры /url?page=1&date=13.01.2017 и в модель загружаются данные по этим параметрам. Выбирая другую страницу / дату значения в url должны устанавливаться на выбранное значение и загружаются новые данные. При этом порядок следования переменных в url не имеет значения. Хотелось бы иметь двустороннюю привязку значения параметра в url и значения модели, чтобы при изменении url модель обновлялась, и при установлении модели в новое значение (например, переход на след. страницу), соответствующее значение отображалось в url. Реализуемо ли это средствами AngularJS? Что-то похожее нашлось в ngRoute, но там с именованными параметрами проблема, т.к. все ориентировано на restful-тип url, т.е. вида /page/1/date/13.01.2017 И как быть с опциональностью некоторых переменных, которые в url могут и не попасть, но какое-то значение по умолчанию у них имеется?

Comment: _Реализуемо ли это средствами AngularJS?_ - да.

Comment: Видимо, логичным будет вопрос "А как?", в какую сторону копать?

Comment: любой роутер: `ngRoute`, `ui-router`

Comment: _там с именованными параметрами проблема_ - там нет с эти проблемы. Неизвестно как именно ты пытался их использовать.

Comment: возможно я вас не понял, что значит: *но там с именованными параметрами проблема*. использую `ngRoute` получаю параметры так `$routeParams.itemId`